# JavaScript: How to get simple date without timezone

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, date-format

I have code that generates random dates in a date range, which gives me dates which, when logged, produce this format:

> Wed Sep 25 2019 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

I just want to get the date without timezone and Day specifically like this:

> 2019-09-25

I am trying to get random dates between specified dates using the following code:

```
    var startDate = new Date("2019-08-26"); //YYYY-MM-DD
    var endDate = new Date("2019-09-25"); //YYYY-MM-DD

    var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
        var arr = new Array();
        var dt = new Date(start);
        while (dt <= end) {
            arr.push(new Date(dt));
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);


    function shuffle(arra1) {
        var ctr = arra1.length, temp, index;

    // While there are elements in the array
        while (ctr > 0) {
           // Pick a random index
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
            // Decrease ctr by 1
            ctr--;
            // And swap the last element with it
            temp = arra1[ctr];
            arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
            arra1[index] = temp;
        }
        return arra1; }

    console.log(shuffle(dateArr));
```

---

It's not a duplicate question as I was trying to achieve different and very specific formate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: You should use moment.js. The docs are extensive but it can do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Igor That's not really a duplicate; the top answers focus on how to achieve an entirely different format than what OP is trying to get.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for Dates?

Comment: @igor  I already applied that solution but it doesn't work for me so I had to ask my question separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to map each item of `arra1` through a custom formating function (ie `formatDate()`) where `.getDate()`, `.getMonth()` and `.getYear()` are used to populate the formatted string:

```
function formatDate(date) {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  /* getMonth returns dates from 0, so add one */
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const day = date.getDate();

  return `${year}-${month < 10 ? '0' : ''}${ month }-${ day < 10 ? '0' : '' }${day}`
}
```

Some points to consider here are:

- `Date#getMonth()` [returns 0-indexed dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth#Return_value) in the range of 0-11. To match the desired date format, you should add `1` as shown
- Check for day and month values that are less than `10` and prefix a `0` to pad those numbers to obtain the desired formatting

This can be added to your existing code as shown:

```js
var startDate = new Date("2019-08-26"); //YYYY-MM-DD
var endDate = new Date("2019-09-25"); //YYYY-MM-DD

function formatDate(date) {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  /* getMonth returns dates from 0, so add one */
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const day = date.getDate();
  
  return `${year}-${month < 10 ? '0' : ''}${ month }-${ day < 10 ? '0' : '' }${day}`
}


var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
  var arr = new Array();
  var dt = new Date(start);
  while (dt <= end) {
    arr.push(new Date(dt));
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return arr;
}

var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);


function shuffle(arra1) {
  var ctr = arra1.length,
    temp, index;

  // While there are elements in the array
  while (ctr > 0) {
    // Pick a random index
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
    // Decrease ctr by 1
    ctr--;
    // And swap the last element with it
    temp = arra1[ctr];
    arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
    arra1[index] = temp;
  }

  /* Update this line */
  return arra1.map(formatDate);
}

console.log(shuffle(dateArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toISOString()` and `.substr()`. Example:

```js
var dt = new Date("2019-09-25");
console.log(dt.toISOString().substr(0,10)); // 2019-09-25
```

The advantage of this approach is that the `Date` object has the `.toISOString()` method built-in, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. That method returns a full ISO string, though, like "2019-09-25T00:00:00.000Z". So, you can use `.substr` to retrieve only the part you want to use.

Comment: it gives me following error:
TypeError: dateArr.toISOString is not a function

Comment: `dateArr` is an array. `.toISOString` is a method of the `Date` object, not of an array. You would need to call it on a particular date, not the array of dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var dates = [],
        currentDate = startDate,
        addDays = function(days) {
            var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

            return date;
    };

    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
        dates.push(currentDate);
        currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
   }

        return dates;
    };

// Usage 
var dates = getDates(new Date(2019, 10, 22),
    new Date(2019, 11, 25));
dates.forEach(function(date) {
    console.log(date);
});
```